# Call recording is capturing only callee's audio in a bidirectional stream however in the connected call both caller and callee's audio can be heared

Tags: twilio, voice

**Objective** : record both caller and callee's audio in a bidirectional media stream

**Setup** :

1. I am using a trial account
2. Using Python client to make and outbound call, url of a webserver is passed ("/answer" in the url parameter)

```
 call = client.calls.create(
    url=f"https://{ngrok}/answer",
    from_="+91XXXXXX",
    to="+91XXXXXX",
    recording_track='both',
    record=True,
    recording_channels='dual', #have also tried mono
    trim='do-not-trim'
)

@app.post("/answer")
async def answer_call():
    """Respond to the incoming call."""
    print("answering call")
    voice_response = VoiceResponse()
    connect = Connect()
    connect.stream(url=f"wss://{ngrok}/test_call")
    voice_response.append(connect)
    return Response(content=str(voice_response), media_type="application/xml")

@app.websocket("/test_call")
async def transcript(ws: WebSocket):
    print("WS connection opened")
    await ws.accept()
    print("accepted socket connection")
    . 
    .
    # After the start event event is received : call recordings api
     recording = client.calls(call_sid) \
    .recordings \
    .create(recording_channels='dual', recording_track='both')
```

3. The `/test_call` url uses a websocket to accept the incoming audio and also responds back audio.

I have tried the below 2 approaches :

**Approach 1** : Record the call using OutboundAPI by passing record=True in client.calls.create()

**Approach 2** : Record the call using Recordings API when the websocket is connected. This is called from the `/test_call` endpoint.

```
recording = client.calls(call_sid) \
    .recordings \
    .create(recording_channels='dual', recording_track='both')
```

**Observations**:

1. When I pick up the call, I can hear the audio returned from this end point but in the call recording acessible in the console, I can hear only callee's audio and not the voice response sent from the `/test_call` endpoint.
2. Using the Outbound API if I use

- recording_track='outbound', I can hear the audio response returned (only caller's audio is captued)
- recording_track='both', **only callee's audio is captured**
- recording_track='inbound', only callee's audio is captured